# Видеоплеер на javascript

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, видео

Возможно ли загрузить видео на youtube и вставить его на сайт(не скачивая на хостинг) с кастомным плеером, а не обычным ютубовским плеером?

Comment: Другими словами, сделать так, чтобы за хостинг и трафик платил Гугл, но рекламы ему не было? Даже если можно технически, я уверен, что это будет нарушать соглашения пользователя, которое вы подписали. Не стоит этого делать.